# Matplotlib Custom Marker Path

Tags: python, matplotlib, marker

I am trying to create custom markers in Matplotlib using the Path instance as documented here:
https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 4, 9, 6]

custommarker = mpl.path.Path([[0,0],[1,1],[1,0]],[1,2,2])
plt.plot(1.5,0,marker=custommarker)

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
plt.show()
```

When I run the Code I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'Path' object does not support indexing
```

In mpl 1.3.x this was working but since mpl 2.x.x I get this error.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suppose you found a bug in matplotlib. However, for all practical purposes there might a simple workaround. Are you trying to plot a filled triangle or a skewed lambda (Λ) ?

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: I am using python 3.6.4 mit mal 2.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

From the complete error message generated from your code, it could be seen that the error is in the function `set_marker` in the actual [`markers.py`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v2.2.x/lib/matplotlib/markers.py) function. As noted by [ImportanceOfBeingErnest in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791084/matplotlib-custom-marker-path/49792991#comment86601881_49792991), this is actually a bug that has already been fixed, but still not released (to date 12/04/2018), as can be seen in the current master version of [`markers.py`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/markers.py).

The code raising the error is the following:

```
if (isinstance(marker, np.ndarray) and marker.ndim == 2 and
        marker.shape[1] == 2):
    self._marker_function = self._set_vertices
elif (isinstance(marker, Sized) and len(marker) in (2, 3) and
        marker[1] in (0, 1, 2, 3)):
    self._marker_function = self._set_tuple_marker
```

And it is not until some `elif` later that the check for `isinstance(marker,Path)` is performed.

One workaround is to trigger the first `if`, to avoid ending up executing `marker[1]`. This condition checks for numpy arrays with dimensions consitent with the vertices of a path object, and instead of passing the `custommarker`, pass its vertices:

```
plt.plot(1.5,0,marker=custommarker.vertices)
```

The other option is to avoid the second `if` using a different lenght for the marker, because only `len(marker) in (2,3)` will give errors:

```
custommarker = mpl.path.Path([(0,0),(1,1),(1,0),(1,0)],[1,2,2,79]) # Or a 0 as final code if instead o closing the line should stop there.
```

Both workarounds give the same result.

Comment: You are referring to the current master branch, where this bug has already been fixed. In previous versions the line checking for `marker[1] in (0, 1, 2, 3)` comes *before* the check for `isinstance(marker,Path)`. Hence the error.

Comment: This has been fixed on current master (see [this PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10632)). It has not yet been released in any version.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks! I have edited the answer

Comment: Thank you for your answers. If it is a known bug and a fix is to be expected I can work with the python Environment where I use an older mpl Version (1.3.x). I did not understand what I was doing wrong. Obviously I wasn't. Thank you for the clarifications.